# Find all possible values of the perimeter of a rectangle with sides $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, where its area is given by $A=3x+3y+\sqrt{9x^2+9y^2}$

Tags: area, factoring, integers, rectangles

Find all possible values of the perimeter of a rectangle with sides positive integers $x$ and $y$ where its area is given by $A=3x+3y+\sqrt{9x^2+9y^2}$

In other words if $xy=3x+3y+\sqrt{9x^2+9y^2}$, find $2(x+y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are positive integers. I'm not sure how to start but maybe I can factor the expression out to make it $3(x+y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ but I can't go any further. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Since $x^2+y^2$ is a square, $(x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ must be a Pythagorean triple.

Answer (score 2):

> This is an application based calculus question. You have find the total $(x , y)$ values suitable under the area/perimeter and +integer restraint. By conventional methods, you **should begin** by expressing $y$ in terms of $x$ to obtain a function of the rectangle's perimeter under a single variable. This eases the next step of differentiating to evaluate the maximum $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ of this perimeter function such that both $x$ and the perimeter are positive. Finally, find all the equivalent $y$-values and eliminate any pair of $(x, y)$ that are not positive integers.

Here is a little help on the factoring to get you started:

> In cases where you have the unknown variable under a root and outside the root, you should first try to remove/eliminate the root term:

$$xy = 3x + 3y + \sqrt{9x^2 + 9y^2}
\\\iff \sqrt{9x^2 + 9y^2} = xy - 3x - 3y
\\\iff 9x^2 + 9y^2 = (xy - 3x - 3y)^2 = 9x^2 + 9y^2 + x^2y^2 - 6x^2y - 6xy^2 + 18xy
\\\iff x^2y^2 - 6x^2y - 6xy^2 + 18xy = 0$$

Can you continue to factor from here?

Comment: I got $y=\frac{6(x-6)}{x-3}$ so the permimeter is $2(x+\frac{6(x-6)}{x-3})$. Do i just differentiate and find the positive values of $x$?

Comment: @sinichgaja It should be $y = \dfrac{6(x - 3)}{(x - 6))}$. There maybe an arithmetic/algebraic error in your work.

Comment: Just tried to find the maximum value of the perimeter function $P(x)=2(x+\frac{6(x-3)}{x-6})$, seems like it doesn't have a maximum value (it has a slant aymptote), does that mean there are infinite values of such a perimeter, or am I doing somethng wrong?

Comment: seems like it still doesn't work

Comment: Yes the rational maximum of the function is infinite. But we want the integer maximum. See that we must have both $x, y$ as positive integers. Observe that $y = \dfrac{6(x - 3)}{(x - 6)} = \dfrac{18}{(x - 6)} + 6$. This means $(x - 6) |18$ and $\dfrac{18}{(x - 6)} + 6 > 0 \implies x \in (0, 3) \cup (6 , \infty)$, in order for $y$ to be a positive integer. However, there are only few factors that divide $18$; $18 = 3 \cdot 6, \,\, 9\cdot2, \,\, 18\cdot 1$.

Comment: This may seem dumb, but how do you go from $\frac{6(x-3)}{x-6}$ to $\frac{18}{x-6}+6$?

Comment: @sinichgaja $$\dfrac{6(x-3)}{x - 6} \\= \dfrac{6x - 18}{x - 6} \\= \dfrac{6x - 36 + 18}{x - 6} \\= \dfrac{6(x - 6) + 18}{x - 6} \\= 6 + \dfrac{18}{x - 6} $$